# Update a date condition in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created multiple cte in sql 2008 in which I have a date condition in all queries that I want to update daily.  Is there a way to put the date condition in variable so I can just update in way one place and not missing all the other dates in the queries, anyway they are all the same value.

Comment: This is nowhere near enough detail to provide a useful answer. Post some of your code, and/or table structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are all in one script, you can use a single variable.

```
Declare @specified_date Date
set @specified_date = '10-29-2014'

update myTable set myDateField = @specified_date
```

Or you can create a field in a table, and update that single field daily, and have all your queries reference that field.

Comment: I can not create a table since I have a read only access to the database.